# Reference a CSS property's value from CSS

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

Suppose I want a div's height to be `1080/1920` times its width, given a fixed width.

How can I achieve something to the effect of:

```css
.item{ width:640px; height:calc(.item.width * 1080/1920); }
```

or even

```css
.item{ width:640px; height:calc(<selector>.width * 1080/1920); }
```

where `<selector>` selects a different CSS class (and `<selector>.width` selects its width)?

(I know you can do this in Javascript, which I already am, but I wonder if there's a CSS-only solution.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to reference a css property from another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258120/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-css-property-from-another-element)

Comment: If what you want to do only involves stretching/scaling/rotating/etc, transform is a good solution as its percent values always refer to the elements own dimensions no matter what type of positioning its using. Also, somewhat weirdly, if you use percentage values for padding-top and padding-bottom, those too will always be based on the elements own width. So you can sometimes figure out some hacky work arounds with padding. Not sure about self-referential height though... that one is always more elusive.

Comment: @diopside That's helpful, thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio